# HTML5 Video incorrect MIME type

Tags: html, iis, video, html5-video

I do not have access to the server settings. I asked who was responsible to add the MIME type `video/mp4`. He added the MIME type but the server is still reporting the incorrect type.

Here is what I get after I run the command `curl -I`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 20:53:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Jun 2014 12:47:46 GMT
ETag: "69843b848581cf1:931"
Content-Length: 8104465
```

The video works in most browsers, but for some reason doesn’t work in older versions of IE. Could there be any other reason why I am getting `application/octet-stream` for the Content-Type?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 video isn’t supported on older IE versions. The best (and probably only) solution is to have a Flash video fallback for older IE versions.

Here’s a manual on how to add a flash video fallback: [Video for Everybody](http://web.archive.org/web/20101205155004/http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody).

Comment: But I can get the video to work in IE9 running on my local server. The issue is that the video doesn't play on the remote server.

Comment: I did some extra research, and apparently in IE9 the mimetype needs to be set to video/mp4 like you requested to the administrator. On newer browsers, the browser automaticly detects that it's a mp4 video. You should ask the administrator again to take a look at it